# How can I use tf.data Datasets in eager execution mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the [tf.data talk](https://youtu.be/uIcqeP7MFH0?t=654) at the TensorFlow Dev Summit 2018, Derek Murray presented a way to combine the [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) API with TensorFlow's eager execution mode (at 10:54). I tried out a simplified version of the code shown there:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random_uniform([50, 10]))
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
for batch in dataset:
    print(batch)
```

causing

```
TypeError: 'BatchDataset' object is not iterable
```

I also tried using `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()` and `dataset.make_initializable_iterator()` to iterate over the dataset, but they result in

```
RuntimeError: dataset.make_one_shot_iterator is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
```

and

```
RuntimeError: dataset.make_initializable_iterator is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
```

*TensorFlow version: 1.7.0, Python version: 3.6*

How can you use the `tf.data` API with eager execution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`make_one_shot_iterator()` should work in TensorFlow 1.8, but for now (i.e., for TensorFlow 1.7), do the following:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.random_uniform([50, 10]))
dataset = dataset.batch(5)
for batch in tfe.Iterator(dataset):
     print(batch)
```

Answer (score 5):

With **TF 2.1**,

You can create an iterator like so:

```
iterator = iter(dataset)
```

And get the next batch of values:

```
batch = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: Doesn't work:
`RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.`. TF2