# Parsing TFRecord when in eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

Considering that [is possible to run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659358/4743714) `tf.Data.Datasets` in eager execution mode, how should I open a TFRecord file on eager execution? I'm more concerned about the parser writing, because I'm currently using `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator` as an iterator (between several images on my container).

Comment: I don't quite follow the question: If you're using a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`, that will work just as well with eager execution enabled.  Perhaps you can update the question with some more detail of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ash when I turn on eager execution, I get the following error just after my parsing method: `RuntimeError: dataset.make_one_shot_iterator is not supported when eager execution is enabled.` . This happens regardless of the chosen iterator method.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're likely using TensorFlow 1.7 or older. Posted an answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TensorFlow 1.8 onwards you can naturally iterate on the `tf.data.Dataset` object with eager execution enabled.

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).map(...).batch(...)
for x in ds:
  print(x)
```

`make_one_shot_iterator` will also work (kept working to keep compatible with equivalent code for graph construction):

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).map(...).batch(...)
itr = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
for x in itr:
  print(x)
```

However, in older versions of TensorFlow (where eager execution is a newly introduced feature and thus less baked), you'll have to wrap your dataset in a `tf.contrib.eager.Iterator`, using something like:

```
tfe  tf.contrib.eager
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).map(...).batch(...)
for x in tfe.Iterator(ds):
  print(x)
```

See these resources associated with the 1.7 release:
- [Notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/notebooks/3_datasets.ipynb)
- [RNN example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a183dee236f69b360479a3aef52ba2f742d6841a/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/rnn_colorbot/rnn_colorbot.py#L199)

Hope that helps.